Digital-to-analog-converter PCB: Ground plane cut or not?
I'm designing a DAC board and I'm not sure what would be the best thing to do regarding grounding, to minimize noise.
This is the approximate layout I have so far, with the system ground point (also the power input) shown at the bottom.

It's a 4-layer board with both inner layers used as ground planes, so ground impedance should be quite low. The fastest signal in the red high-speed area is a ~25 MHz system clock, the DAC sample rate is < 200 kHz.
My question is: Would it make sense in this case to introduce a ground plane cut, such as the one shown in yellow, in order to guide ground return currents from the high-speed section away from the analog section?
I'm quite sure (from the DAC datasheet and other info online) that there should be no ground cut between the digital and analog sections of the DAC itself. But is a partial cut like this, around the other high-speed circuits, likely to improve noise performance in any way? There seems to be a lot of conflicting information about these things from different sources and manufacturers, and I'm not sure who to believe.

I'd use local planes for return currents, and then join them at a single point that connects to a bigger, non-current-carrying plane. That is what I did on my LCD monitor and single-board computer designs which involve different high-frequency sub-circuits.

I suggest this video https://youtu.be/19WnYPhNOH0?si=5halJDLPAWK0Yx9J

The high frequency digital won't be such a problem since the ground current will minimize inductance by staying directly under signal lines, so as long as your signal routing is good, so will your return currents. The harder question is the lower frequency digital, since at 100s of KHz resistance won't be completely dominated by inductive reactance making it harder to predict exactly where return currents go.

Where would you route traces? Where are the current flows on the board? What outside connections (cables etc.) are there?  FYI, EMC is a complex, interconnected topic, and EMC problems are holistic in nature.  There is generally very little that can be said about a problem without also completely describing the setup and environment.

Ground plane separation is not necessary. It is good practice where feasible, and improves performance. Specifically, it keeps digital noise out of the analog circuits. How much benefit that translates to depends heavily on how noisy the digital circuits are, how sensitive the analog circuits and the application are, and how well the circuits are designed otherwise.
Since you're already using ground plane(s), you already have your ground impedance low enough. That's good.
Though the return currents flow through the ground plane, remember that the return currents are not necessarily straight lines, and for practical purposes they don't fill the ground plane entirely. At higher frequencies, the return current tends to follow the path of the main signal trace. (I don't think 200kHz is high enough frequency for that to be the dominant effect, though)
Any return currents flowing through the area of your sensitive analog circuits will add a little noise to your noise floor. Careful placement of the components and circuits can by itself guide the return currents from your digital circuits away from the analog ones, and this might be enough for less demanding applications.
Actually working out the return paths in complex circuits with a lot of things going on can be slightly tricky, though. Placing a ground plane cut can force the return currents to route away from sensitive areas.
However, note that the ground plane cut by itself might not be enough. In higher frequency circuits, if you have traces crossing the ground plane cut, the return path might follow the edge of the cut, turn around it, and follow it back to the original signal trace and continue on the original path. The currents at higher frequencies arrange themselves to minimize loop area, so just adding that cut might introduce a loop large enough to generate enough EMI which can get coupled to your analog circuits, making things worse.
So, whenever you're separating grounds, you also ensure that there is no copper crossing that ground separation barrier. Any traces which need to move from one side to the other should do so at the point at which the grounds are connected together. Any copper which does not need to cross the barrier at all, but which can go around, should go around.
Since you're using a 4 layer board, you should also ensure that there is no overlap on adjacent layers (or, more specifically, unscreened layers) of two different ground areas. The capacitive coupling across the layers can also cause noise to be coupled in. The 'safe' starting point is to designate certain areas of the board as Analog or Digital across all layers of the board. When you need a dense circuit, you generally take other precautions, such as adding additional internal ground layers to screen the top half of the stack from the bottom half, for example.
The cut in the ground is enough for more regular applications. The cut, and your effort to ensure nothing crosses the cut, ensures that you design in such a way that return currents are generally well separated. The best way to do this, in my experience, is just treat them as separate grounds for most of the design. At the end, I connect the two grounds together at a single point or along a short edge, often near the DAC. For your application, most likely it would be somewhere near the DAC's digital inputs, just outside the DAC IC's boundaries.
As you've noted, the DAC itself is a single ground IC. Most Analog Digital interface ICs such as ADCs and DACs are. When they present two separated named grounds, such as AGND and DGND, those are separate in the IC itself, and you need to treat them as separate, but the best performance is obtained by having the two shorted together very close to the ADC or DAC (Which gets messy when you have more than one ADC/DAC). You can't actually have a significant potential difference between the two grounds. The particular ICs datasheet or layout guidelines may tell you how to treat the ground plane under the IC itself.
For the most demanding applications, you'd have separate analog and digital grounds at the system / PCB level which are galvanically isolated. The digital ground would be under your controller and other purely digital circuits, and the analog ground would be under analog circuits and things like the ADCs and DACs. Note that what the DAC or ADC calls a "Digital Ground" will actually be derived from your system's Analog Ground, but done in such a way that digital switching noises are contained to a small area by using decoupling capacitors and careful placement and routing. Digital lines would cross from one system ground domain to the other though isolators.
There are going to be instances where the space required for good separation is more expensive than the value obtained by lowering the noise floor for that application. There are going to be applications where the cost of full galvanic isolation is less than the value obtained by lowering the noise floor. In each instance, you would need to evaluate what is necessary and try to strike some kind of balance.

Ground plane cuts are all about managing the return currents.

If the return currents from the high speed digital circuitry go underneath the DAC, the return currents along with the PCB plane resistance will cause a voltage on the ground of the DAC (V=I*R). This voltage will be different from the analog circuit ground because there is no return current, therefore the signal of the DAC will have a voltage noise offset relative to the analog circuit.
If the return currents are going underneath the DAC, you may want to cut the plane to route them around the DAC. Another option is to place the DAC in a different location.

Curious: what is a typical magnitude of digital currents, and what is a typical magnitude of plane resistance? How many ENOB would be necessary for this effect to be relevant? || Ground cuts are NOT for free. Where high-frequency currents are disallowed from flowing, magnetic fields shoot out as if to complain. It is rarely the case that a ground cut is a good idea overall, and there exist much better solutions for almost all situations (e.g. differential design).

I agree, component placement is the best strategy for minimizing noise.
